# conversion from sql date time to .NET date time always results in 0

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, datetime

I am having this line, although there is a text (which is `dd/mm/yyyy`) format, in the dropdown list, I see `0` as selected index because, the EndDate is SQL `Datetime` format.

```
ddlScheduleEnd.SelectedIndex = ddlScheduleEnd.Items.IndexOf(ddlScheduleEnd.Items.FindByText(_benefitSchedule.EndDate.ToString()));
```

I tried to use overload of `ToString()` but no luck.

Found answer myself: This worked best, the trick is, "**Value**"

```
ddlScheduleEnd.SelectedIndex = ddlScheduleEnd.Items.IndexOf(ddlScheduleEnd.Items.FindByText(_benefitSchedule.EndDate.Value.ToString(_dateFormatInternal)));
```

Comment: Just to be sure, the element you are looking for isn't the first element, right?

Comment: @Namfuak: lol you are not the answer I found it myself